# Activity dialog with tab

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-tabs

I am building application for tab.

1. On click of button I am trying to show  Activity (say **A**) with theme `@android:style/Theme.Dialog`
2. Inside activity **A** I am creating actionbar and adding 4 tabs.
3. On click of tab I want to change fragment.

Everything works fine until I am not applying theme `@android:style/Theme.Dialog`
After applying theme I am getting exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ebuilder/com.ebuilder.views.MyTabActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

at following line:

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_home).
                    setTabListener(homeListener), 0);
```

I have two questions:

**1. What is going wrong if I apply theme dialog?**

**2. Is my approach right?**

Let me know if anybody know another approach.

**Edit1:**
**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vivek"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk  android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FragmentInsideFragmentTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomDialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**res/values/style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
            <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>        
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Edit2**

```
05-03 21:42:10.580: D/AndroidRuntime(533): Shutting down VM
05-03 21:42:10.580: W/dalvikvm(533): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vivek/com.vivek.FragmentInsideFragmentTestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.init(ActionBarImpl.java:214)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.<init>(ActionBarImpl.java:192)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Activity.initActionBar(Activity.java:1767)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1781)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at com.vivek.FragmentInsideFragmentTestActivity.onCreate(FragmentInsideFragmentTestActivity.java:47)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
05-03 21:42:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I'd recommend to build the tab in bites instead of doing it in one big chunk. Then you can pinpoint exacly what gives nullpointer. Nullpointer should be fairly simple to solve.

Comment: no actually actionBar itself is null if I apply theme `Theme.Dialog` hence the exception.

Comment: My guess (its a guess) is that dialog theme doesn't have title and since actionbar deep down is a titlebar this means there is no actionbar hence null. Is it possible to use a different theme?

Comment: Could you post the complete exception stack?

Comment: Remove the `windowNoTitle` property from the custom theme and try.

Comment: @Dharmendra Same exception is coming after removing  mention attribute

Comment: See a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425020/actionbar-in-a-dialogfragment

Answer (score 1):

I`m struggling with the same issue here and found two different approaches so far.

The first one described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/Y5wnstMT5Lo/upOijj1OOJIJ) is the one I used.

There was also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700537/how-to-open-activity-as-a-dialog-with-actionbar) answer that looks very similar to the first.

The big problem seems to be that the ActionBar is only supposed to be used on a fullscreen Layout, so anything trying to apply a Dialog type layout will cause an exception. So that's why both of them are setting the Width at `this.getWindow().setAttributes` with a fixed value, to work around the issue.

That was the conclusion I came up with, hope it helps anyone else looking for this, since this is a very old question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom dialog theme by overriding the properties of dialog that you dont need for an action bar.. Also add the `android:windowActionBar` property to it.

```
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: If I apply this theme getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout
` this error

Comment: This should work. Are you sure you have put `parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog"` attribute in the style tag? try without the `windowNoTitle` item..

Comment: Hey change the `Theme.dialog` to `android:Theme.Holo.Dialog` equivalent. This is the default Dialog theme for applications targeting Honeycomb or newer. `Theme.dialog` is reported as broken...